# OpenGL: Get lookAt center from position and orientation with quaternion

Tags: math, opengl-es, quaternions

I'm working with OpenGL ES 2.0 on an Android augmented reality application. I would like to position the openGL camera at the exact same location as my headset (in terms of position and orientation in space). I have access to the position and orientation of the headset in real-time, but the orientation is based on a quaternion.

**What I have tried so far:** I converted the quaternion to Euler angles to have yaw, pitch and roll angles (which seems fine), and then computed a direction vector :

```
    float ray = 1.0f;
    directionX = ray * (float) (Math.cos(rollRadian) * Math.sin(yawRadian));
    directionY = ray * (float) (Math.cos(rollRadian) * Math.cos(yawRadian));
    directionZ = ray * (float) Math.sin(rollRadian);
```

Then, I update my LookAt values :

```
    // LookAt = translation + direction
    mLookAt[0] = headSetX + directionX;
    mLookAt[1] = headSetY + directionY;
    mLookAt[2] = headSetZ + directionZ;
```

However, it seems that the direction values are too weak compared to the headset translation, resulting in an incorrect display (ex: I can see my virtual object even when I'm not looking in its direction). I suspect that a part of the issue is related to the *ray* parameter in the formula above, which was from [this question in StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385137/calculate-3d-vector-out-of-two-angles-and-vector-length)

**Questions:** Did I miss something with this implementation ? Is there another way to get a LookAt vector (or directly the point where I'm looking to) from a position in world-space and a orientation quaternion ?

Comment: Don't bother with Euler angles. Simply convert the quaternion + translation directly to a matrix and use its inverse as the view matrix.

Comment: Additionally, `roll` should only affect the side vectors, not the direction vector.